# Framing ceiling opening above two windows

Tags: framing

I am currently in the process of purchasing a Mitsubishi MLZ Ceiling Cassette. However, the current joist run in my house is from the front to the back. I have two windows in the front of the house, and I would like to install the cassette in the ceiling between the two windows, which means it will be perpendicular to the joists.
R802.9 Framing of openings does not mention whether a box frame is allowed to be installed above a window or not. The transfer of load will now be located just above the header of the window. Only 3-4 joists will be affected, and I only need to remove at least 2-3 feet from the wall to box it in for the cassette. I plan to add extra trimmers, headers, and hangers to ensure sufficient support. Would that be sufficient?
Ceiling has 2x8 construction and walls are 2x4.

Answer (score 0):

Crazy thing about building code is…. It’s hard to figure out. I’ve been a Building Inspector for thirty two years.  When the code is silent about a subject, then on comes interpretation and (OMG) common sense.  From my experience, most headers are over designed because it’s easier and quicker to frame up.  You most likely are ok. But, we don’t know the load of the roof assembly or the load on the ceiling joists. If there is an attic above, it’s pretty easy to beef up the framing from above.  Don’t even try to find that referenced in the code. I hope this helpss